# how can I create an alert dialog box in a subclass of the main class in android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a main class which extends MapActivity and I'm going to create alert dialog in a subclass, but I encountered an error of Context parameter.
here is my java code:

public class main extends MapActivity {

```
private MapView mapView;
private MapController mapController;
private GeoPoint geopoint;

public class MapOverlay extends Overlay {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapv){

        if(event.getAction()==1){
            GeoPoint p = mapv.getProjection().fromPixels(
                    (int) event.getX(), 
                    (int) event.getY());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location: " + 
                    p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6 + "," +
                    p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();    
            ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button  
            ad.setMessage("Hello World");  
            ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
                    dialog.dismiss();                      
                }  
            });  
            ad.show(); 
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

}

The error is:

> The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(main.MapOverlay) is undefined!

I changed this to `getBaseContext()`, but I encountered Force Close error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to a valid context from the `MapView` reference using the inherited  [`getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29) method. The relevant line would then be:

```
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(mapv.getContext()).create();
```